# Arduino - Rural A-GPS Station

Tags: arduino-uno

I'm trying to set up a GPS tracking solution in a rural area. The catch is the GPS trackers need to be lower cost (power and cash), because there will be a good amount of them.

So I'm trying to find a solution where I can benefit from A-GPS using a beacon of some sort to handle any cpu/server calculations while receiving GPS noise from the tracking devices (I think that's the idea). I've read up a bit on Mobile Station Assisted (MSA) GPS, but I'm not entirely sure what solutions there are to handle this.

Any help or advice is appreciated.

Example:

Arduino GPS tracker x 200 ---[RF comms/GPS noise]--->  Beacon/Tower  ---[Internet]---> GPS Server

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I get what you want, but the A7 module of Ai-Thinker is a good GPRS module with GPS in it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've already got GPS board solution (Simduino) but I'm just trying to find out how I can use Assisted GPS without having each tracker communicate with the GPS server. The solution I researched uses a single beacon to do all the grunt work for the Assisted server stuff and the trackers help it by sending low-power GPS noise.


I just don't know of any software solution to create this tracker->beacon->server communication

Comment: got it, sorry but i don't have any idea how to help you.